# Airflow Dag Alignment not getting correct

Tags: python, airflow, postgres-operator

I have a dag where I am runnnig diff sql queries based on the countries.
I want to make an airflow dag where out of 4 queries my 1st query is diff but the other queries are pretty much same.

what I mean by first query diff is that it has diff columns but then the other process does the same job of update, insert etc.
I am little confused how can i do that.

My Process:

1. Shortcircuit operator check if there is new data in the table or not.
2. If no new data based on timestamp which is stored in s3 directory skip the rest of the dag
   3.If new data then based on the country run the dag, I am running my Shortcircuit Operator in for loop for countries  countries = ["INDIA","ZAMBIA","USA"]. All of these have diff query but then in second step they all do the same process of update and delete

I used the branch operator but couldn't quite get that correctly.

I want to acheieve something like below image or I may be wrong but suggest

[image]

UPDATE:
I was able to solve this!

Comment: Do you want to have 3 circuit operators or only one which is run before 3 postgres operators? There should be only one upsert operation?

Comment: @TomaszUrbaszek, Thanks for the reply but I was able to solve this actually